# How to build dynamic query with expression tree for PLINQ

Tags: c#, expression-trees, plinq

I want to bild customized OrderBy for PLINQ, but I don't know how to.

For IQueryable, use can use below code:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string sortProperty, ListSortDirection sortOrder)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var property = type.GetProperty(sortProperty);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
        var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
        var typeArguments = new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType };
        var methodName = sortOrder == ListSortDirection.Ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";
        var resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), methodName, typeArguments, source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExp));

        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
    }
}
```

But for ParallelQuery, there's no such property Provider and Expresss.
Does anybody know how to do?

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static ParallelQuery<T> OrderBy<T>(this ParallelQuery<T> source, string sortProperty, ListSortDirection sortOrder)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `IQueryable`, you don't need `Provider` for this, it's enough to create the expression and then directly call `OrderBy`/`OrderByDescending`. The only problem is that `OrderBy()` is generic in the type of the sorting property, which you don't know (not statically).

You can work around that by invoking `OrderBy()` using reflection. Or you can use `dynamic`:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string sortProperty, ListSortDirection sortOrder)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var property = type.GetProperty(sortProperty);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
    var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);

    if (sortOrder == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        return Queryable.OrderBy(source, (dynamic)orderByExp);
    }
    else
    {
        return Queryable.OrderByDescending(source, (dynamic)orderByExp);
    }
}
```

And you can use exactly the same with PLINQ:

```
public static ParallelQuery<T> OrderBy<T>(this ParallelQuery<T> source, string sortProperty, ListSortDirection sortOrder)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var property = type.GetProperty(sortProperty);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
    var orderByFunc = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter).Compile();

    if (sortOrder == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        return ParallelEnumerable.OrderBy(source, (dynamic)orderByFunc);
    }
    else
    {
        return ParallelEnumerable.OrderByDescending(source, (dynamic)orderByFunc);
    }
}
```

Comment: One more question, how to avoid boxing/unboxing if I have the sortProperty returns type object, but always stored the value hasing integer type?

Comment: @luciferlu If the type of the property is `object`, then the value will be already boxed, no matter what. And I think this code won't unbox it.

Comment: in the case I mentioned, somehow, we can add below code to improve the perfomrance: propertyAccess = Expression.Convert(propertyAccess, [target type])

Answer (score 0):

Just call `AsQueryable` on your parallel query, and then call `AsParallel` when done to get back a parallel query:

```
public static ParallelQuery<T> OrderBy<T>(this ParallelQuery<T> source, 
    string sortProperty, ListSortDirection sortOrder)
{
    return source.AsQueryable()
        .OrderBy(sortProperty, sortOrder)
        .AsParallel();
}
```

Comment: But will this actually execute that `OrderBy()` in parallel?

Comment: Thanks, but actually this can't work. It will throw StackOverflow.