# C# How to use AsParallel conditionally or attach dynamically at runtime

Tags: c#, plinq

this is a sample join between two datatable by LINQ

```
 var JoinResult = (from p in dt.AsEnumerable()  
                   join t in dtTax.AsEnumerable()  
                   on p.Field<int>("Tax Id") equals t.Field<int>("Tax Id")  
                   select new  
                   {  
                       ProductName = p.Field<string>("Product Name"),  
                       BrandName = p.Field<string>("Brand Name"),  
                       ProductCategory = t.Field<string>("Product Category"),  
                       TaxCharge = t.Field<int>("Charge")   
                   }).ToList();
```

some time there could be huge amount of data in two datatable and some time two datatable has small amount of data. when data is small amount then **AsParallel()** not require because i know **AsParallel()** will slow down when run for small amount of data but when data volume is big then **AsParallel()** works good & fast.

please tell me how could i use **AsParallel()** dynamically as a result when data volume will be large and same way **AsParallel()** will not be applied when data volume will be small.

[How to build dynamic query with expression tree for PLINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928082/how-to-build-dynamic-query-with-expression-tree-for-plinq)

i found no good solution for my scenario to attach **AsParallel()** with my linq query dynamically. please share the know to achieve my goal. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make two execution branches, one of which uses `AsParallel()`.

```
if (hugeAmountOfData)
{
    result = (
                 ...
                 query.AsParallel()
                 ...
             ).ToList();
}
else
{
    result = (
                 ...
                 query
                 ...
             ).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I don't think it's possible. LINQ and PLINQ have different operators. LINQ operators operate on `IEnumerable<T>`s, while PLINQ operators operate on `ParallelQuery<T>`s. So although the two versions of the query (with and without `AsParallel`) look exactly identical, they are fundamentally two completely different queries.