# Conditionally use PLINQ with minimal code duplication

Tags: c#, linq, plinq

I have some LINQ code that under some conditions, which I can test for, benefits from parallelization.
I would like to use PLINQ when such conditions apply, but also avoid to have all the processing code written twice in different places.

What I tried to do is something like this:

```
var list = ...
bool doParallel = ...
var listEnumerable = doParallel ? list.AsParallel() : list.AsEnumerable();

var result = listEnumerable
      .Select(...);
```

This doesn't work though. `listEnumerable` is considered `IEnumerable` and the `Select` called is always `Enumerable.Select`, the single-thread one.

Edit: the answers in [C# How to use AsParallel conditionally or attach dynamically at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66934269/c-sharp-how-to-use-asparallel-conditionally-or-attach-dynamically-at-runtime) do not answer my question because I am asking how to *avoid* exactly the kind of duplication suggested therein.

Comment: `.WithDegreeOfParallelism(doParallel ? Environment.ProcessorCount : 1)`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: this assumes PLINQ uses `Environment.ProcessorCount` as the DOP by default -- I don't know if it's true but I wouldn't assume it. I'd just to `doParallel ? list.AsParallel() : list.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(1)`. Even then it's important to note that PLINQ with DOP 1 is not necessarily equivalent to "plain LINQ", in particular the performance might go down a bit from parallel algorithms running sequentially as opposed to specifically sequential algorithms. (I don't know if it actually does; PLINQ may be clever enough to avoid that altogether.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert the default degree of parallelism in PLINQ [is indeed](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.core/system/linq/Parallel/Scheduling/Scheduling.cs.html#df4daefa7f756d38) `Environment.ProcessorCount`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: unless you have more than 512 processors, apparently, but let's discount that edge case. :P In any case, I'm wary of relying on implementation details like that -- it's not formally documented (that I could find), so if PLINQ tomorrow switches to some more advanced implementation where it dynamically tunes DOP, but only if you don't explicitly specify it, I'd like my code to take advantage of it.

Comment: @rzippo whether two questions are duplicates is judged by their content, not by the answers they have received. Honestly I don't think that any potential answer to your question would not be also a valid answer for the [question linked as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66934269/c-sharp-how-to-use-asparallel-conditionally-or-attach-dynamically-at-runtime), and by this criterion the two questions are similar enough to be marked as duplicates.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias then how am I supposed to attract new inputs, such as the ones received here, when a previous question did not address what I am actually looking for? The author of the other question was satisfied with the answer suggesting duplication, I did not, and I think this difference his highlighted enough in this question.

Comment: Attracting attention to questions for better answers is what [bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) are supposed to achieve, although realistically, just asking the question again and crossing your fingers that people won't dupe it as an old one is the more common technique.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I found this [in the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq#degree-of-parallelism): *"By default, PLINQ uses all of the processors on the host computer."*, which is not 100% explicit, but it's good enough for me. :-) PLINQ is a technology that is now too old (12+ years) for the Microsoft to start messing with it's fundamental defaults IMHO. You can also check [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/paralleloptions-maxdegreeofparallelism-vs-plinqs-withdegreeofparallelism/) out, if you have spare time.